# Functional components cannot be given refs with react-native-rich-editor on Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to use this package :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pell-rich-editor

And I have the following code :

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { RFPercentage } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";
import BottomSheet from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Platform,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import {
  actions,
  RichEditor,
  RichToolbar,
} from "react-native-pell-rich-editor";

export default function Publish() {

  const postSheetRef = useRef(null);
  const richText = useRef();

  const snapPoints = ["90%"];
    
  };

 return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.publishHeader}>
          <Text style={styles.titleHeader}>Publier un post</Text>
        </View>
        <BottomSheet
          ref={postSheetRef}
          snapPoints={snapPoints}
          handleIndicatorStyle={{ display: "none" }}
        >
          <View style={styles.main}>
            <SafeAreaView>
              <ScrollView>
                  <RichEditor
                    ref={richText}
                    onChange={(descriptionText) => {
                      console.log("descriptionText:", descriptionText);
                    }}
                  />
              </ScrollView>

              <RichToolbar
                editor={richText}
                actions={[
                  actions.setBold,
                  actions.setItalic,
                  actions.setUnderline,
                  actions.heading1,
                ]}
                iconMap={{
                  [actions.heading1]: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <Text style={[{ color: tintColor }]}>H1</Text>
                  ),
                }}
              />
            </SafeAreaView>
          </View>
        </BottomSheet>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

I get this error :

```
Functional components cannot be given refs
```

It concerns the Rich Editor component.

But I just followed the documentation, so I can't understand why.

I use ref with the Bottom sheet component and it works perfectly.

I am working with Expo.

How can I solve this ? This is the only package I have found that is compatible with Expo so I need to make it work ^^.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RichEditor
    ref={(r)=>{richText.current = r}}
    onChange={(descriptionText) => {
        console.log("descriptionText:", descriptionText);
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have the same error :(

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.